# Can Ansible "echo" items as it installs them?

Tags: ansible

I have a rather long task in my Ansible playbook that installs various packages using APT. This tasks takes a very long time on my laptop. Is there any way to get Ansible to "echo" which item it's installing as it iterates through the packages so I can get an idea of how much longer this task is going to take?

```
- name: install global packages
  apt: pkg={{ item }} update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=3600
  become: True
  become_user: root
  with_items:
    - git
    - vim
    - bash-completion
    - bash-doc
    - wput
    - tree
    - colordiff
    - libjpeg62-turbo-dev
    - libopenjpeg-dev
    - zlib1g-dev
    - libwebp-dev
    - libffi-dev
    - libncurses5-dev
    - python-setuptools
    - python-dev
    - python-doc
    - python-pip
    - virtualenv
    - virtualenvwrapper
    - python-psycopg2
    - postgresql-9.4
    - postgresql-server-dev-9.4
    - postgresql-contrib
    - postgresql-doc-9.4
    - postgresql-client
    - postgresql-contrib-9.4
    - postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1
    - postgis-doc
    - postgis
    - nginx
    - supervisor
    - redis-server
```

Comment: what command are you using to run this? have you added `-vvv`?

Comment: I know I can use -vvv but that shows way more information than I need to see.  It would be nice to have a flag that, when set, just says "Installing package1, Installing package2, ..." etc.

Comment: I had the same issue which I fixed with a simple one line tweak to my ansible install. Interested in that solution?

Comment: @Robert I have given a solution. It works for me. All you have to do is edit a line in ansible install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I want a bit more feedback on the playbook run I'll group packages together by their purpose. The `cache_valid_time` allows you to do this without the normal penalty of updating the repo cache each time. I find this improves readability and documentation as well.

```
- name: install global packages
  apt: pkg={{ item }} update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=3600
  become: True
  with_items:
    - git
    - vim
    - bash-completion
    - bash-doc
    - wput
    - tree
    - colordiff
    - libjpeg62-turbo-dev
    - libopenjpeg-dev
    - zlib1g-dev
    - libwebp-dev
    - libffi-dev
    - libncurses5-dev

- name: install python and friends
  apt: pkg={{ item }} update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=3600
  become: True
  with_items:
    - python-setuptools
    - python-dev
    - python-doc
    - python-pip
    - virtualenv
    - virtualenvwrapper
    - python-psycopg2

- name: install postgresql
  apt: pkg={{ item }} update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=3600
  become: True
  with_items:
    - postgresql-9.4
    - postgresql-server-dev-9.4
    - postgresql-contrib
    - postgresql-doc-9.4
    - postgresql-client
    - postgresql-contrib-9.4
    - postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1

- name: install postgis
  apt: pkg={{ item }} update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=3600
  become: True
  with_items:
    - postgis-doc
    - postgis

- name: install nginx
  apt: pkg=nginx update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=3600
  become: True

- name: install supervisor
  apt: pkg=supervisor update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=3600
  become: True

- name: install redis
  apt: pkg=redis-server update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=3600
  become: True
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, Ansible actually does exactly that. It would output every item separately. Which under the hood means: It builds a python package, uploads it to the host(s) and executes it - for every item.

The `apt` and `yum` modules have been optimized for loops. Instead of looping over every item, Ansible builds a package that installs all loop items in one go.

Your command translates to something like this:

```
apt-get -y install git vim bash-completion bash-doc wput ...
```

So in this case, no, there is no way to output the separate steps to see where Ansible is. Because there are no separate steps.

The docs for the `apt` module is missing the note which is available in the  [`yum` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html) page:

> When used with a loop of package names in a playbook, ansible optimizes the call to the yum module. Instead of calling the module with a single package each time through the loop, ansible calls the module once with all of the package names from the loop.

When you work with remote machines, this is actually a preferable behavior. This speeds up the play by a lot. If you run your playbook locally, of course there is not much benefit.

A simple workaround would be to simply not use the apt module but run a shell command.

```
- name: install global packages
  shell: apt-get -y install {{ item }}
  become: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Find your ansible install directory using:

```
> python -c 'import ansible; print ansible.__file__'
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/__init__.pyc
```

Backup the `<ansible_install>/runner/__init__.py` file

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py
```

Edit the file, search for 'apt' and remove 'apt' from the list.

```
if len(items) and utils.is_list_of_strings(items) and self.module_name in [ 'apt', 'yum', 'pkgng' ]:
```

to

```
if len(items) and utils.is_list_of_strings(items) and self.module_name in [ 'yum', 'pkgng' ]:
```

Thats it!

Comment: This is an interesting approach which I'll check out.  However, I'm not a big fan of monkey-patching.